# How to tell browser to render percentage with more pixels?

Tags: html, css

I have a box with a height of `0.1em` and a container with font size `14px`. When I position my box inside the container with a `top` with percentage, sometimes the box's computed height is larger depending on the percentage position.

I want to make my element respond by simply changing the font size of the container (I cannot use `rem` for reasons). eg. container starts at `10px` then goes `12px`, `14px`, etc.

Is there a way to tell the browser to always render my box's height with more pixels (or less pixels) so that it always looks the same regardless of top position?

The SCSS I have to reproduce it (see the codepen for it working):

```
.container {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2em;

  .background {
    width: 2em;
    height: 10em;
    background: lightblue;
    position: relative;

    .line {
      height: 0.1em;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: black;
    }
  }
}
```

Demo of the problem I have: https://codepen.io/jared-hexagon/pen/KKKvxKQ

Tested in Chrome OSX latest with MacBook retina display and a low dpi display - both have the problem.

Comment: Why not use 1px instead of 0.1em? Tested it on your demo and seems to work fine when the height is an integer. Not sure why, but when the height (in pixels) is not an integer, I get the problem you described.

Comment: @Kei I want it to be (kind of) responsive: when I change the container font size everything should scale up. Like when you use `rem` but I am limited in that I cannot use it.